# Error occurs: NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, svm

I have a very large dataset I have to train a model. I don't know where is Nan or missing values. The error occurs when svm code starts.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Data.txt',delimiter=',')
df.head() 
X = df[['a', 'b', 'c']].values   
Y=df['Label'].values

cv = KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=42, shuffle=False)
for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X):
    print("Train Index: ", train_index, "\n")
    print("Test Index: ", test_index)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = X[train_index], X[test_index], Y[train_index], Y[test_index]

svm1 = svm.SVC(gamma='scale', probability=True)
pred = svm1.fit(X_train, Y_train).predict(X_test)
```

error

```
 raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have NaN values in your X.

You have to search them, and deal with it. You can drop the sample, change the values for the mean,.... whatever you decide. But you can't have any NaN value when training.

To detect where this NaN values are use the function `isnull()`. For example, the code below will tell you how many NaN you have for each column:

```
 df.isnull().sum()
```

Once you have this information, you have to decide what to do. For example, if you have just a few samples that have NaN values, I recommend you drop directly all these samples that have these values doing:

```
df.dropna()
```

Another option is that all NaN appears only in one column (feature), in this case, you should evaluate why is this happening and think if you should drop the feature.

As you can see, it depends on every case. In general, any decision you take will be correct if it's correctly justified, but, of course, you have to be aware that results will depend on these preprocess.